# Simple product catalogue website with wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, product

I want to build a website that displays product category wise. And basic features like product detail page on clicking a product. Owner can add and remove product anytime. I do not want to sell online or have add to cart feature or any such things.

I have built website from scratch before. I want to use wordpress for this and have basic knowledge of wordpress. How can it be used to build this website quickly? I read about woocommerce plugin. Is it right choice? Or is there any Free theme/plugin that can be used?

Any guidance and links to resources will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585441/woocommerce-plugin-nested-products-for-subcategories/32602389#32602389) 
this will guide you to do your job and you can remove the add to cart button from all pages by using

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

and restrict user from adding product to cart  `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook to see how visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601753/how-i-can-validate-whenever-a-product-is-added-to-cart-solved)