# How to Programmatically Do Infinite Recursion With PHP

Tags: php, recursion, laravel-5.1

I have a list of questions. Each question can have children and children can also have children. My database is set up as follows:

```
id: incrementing id, question: string, parentId: integer, industryId: integer
```

So basically when i save a parent level question it goes in with a parent ID of "0". If that question was saved as id = 1. Then the sub child would be parentId = 1 and so on.

I need to infinitely loop through the products array to determine if there are more children, but i can't figure out a way to do it that is not manual. Here is my code:

```
<?php
        //Does this question have sub questions?
        $hasChildren = FALSE;
        foreach($questions as $q) {
            if($q->parentId === $question->id) {
                $hasChildren = TRUE;
            }
        }
        if($hasChildren === TRUE): 
        $unique = uniqid();
        ?>
        <ul class="sub-list-{{$unique}}">
            @foreach($questions as $q)
            @if($q->parentId === $question->id)
            <li>{{$q->question}}

                <?php
                //Does this question have sub questions?
                $hasChildren = FALSE;
                foreach($questions as $q1) {
                    if($q1->parentId === $q->id) {
                        $hasChildren = TRUE;
                    }
                }
                if($hasChildren === TRUE): 
                $unique = uniqid();
                ?>
                <ul class="sub-list-{{$unique}}">
                    @foreach($questions as $q1)
                    @if($q1->parentId === $q->id)
                    <li>{{$q1->question}}

                    </li>
                    @endif
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </li>
            @endif
            @endforeach
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have not used laravel 5.1 for any application and before a year I have used laravel 4.2, I can suggest to make a blade like making a nav.blade which again include it, if it is possible, no idea if it is possible.I have done something like that in wordpress/woocommerce , but how you will implement it here, no idea.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585441/woocommerce-plugin-nested-products-for-subcategories/32602389#32602389  you can see here I have done something like that.

Comment: recursive function sounds the way to go, moving the child printing into this function, then for each question, call it to print children, if a child has others children, call the function with the current child id to print its children or close the tag. I don't use laravel but I can write an example code in base php if you wish.